# UISegmentedControl and .selectedSegmentIndex wrong values?

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I have a simple Segment in my code with 3 elements. For testing purposes I also do have a variable that increments based on which of the segments I press (3). The value of that variable is printed in a UITextView. This is the code:

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController
{
    @IBOutlet weak var segment: UISegmentedControl!
    @IBOutlet weak var prwtoView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var prwtoText: UITextField!

    var i : Int = 0

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool)
    {
        prwtoText.backgroundColor = UIColor.purpleColor()
        prwtoText.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        segment.setTitle("Zero", forSegmentAtIndex: 0)
        segment.addTarget(self, action: "action", forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)
        segment.insertSegmentWithTitle("random", atIndex: 2, animated: false)
    }
    func action()
    {
        let argumentForSegment = segment.selectedSegmentIndex
        if argumentForSegment == 0
        {
            i = 0
        }
        if argumentForSegment == 1
        {
            i += 2
        }
        else
        {
            i += Int(arc4random_uniform(100))
        }
        print(argumentForSegment)
        prwtoText.text = "\(i)"
    }

}
```

While I know that it starts with value `-1` i don't want my app to do anything if not pressed. The thing is that even when I press the first segment (0) and it is supposed to make `i = 0` it doesn't do that, although if I print `argumentForSegment` in my terminal it does show the 0 as value. Concluding, every time I press the zero segment (0), my `i` value won't become 0. Perhaps I am using the wrong method from `UISegmentedControl`?

edit: Got it fixed by changing the following code:

```
func action()
{
    let argumentForSegment = segment.selectedSegmentIndex
    if argumentForSegment == 0
    {
        i = 0
    }
    if argumentForSegment == 1
    {
        i += 2
    }
    else
    {
        i += Int(arc4random_uniform(100))
    }
    print(argumentForSegment)
    prwtoText.text = "\(i)"
}
```

to:

```
func action()
{
    let argumentForSegment = segment.selectedSegmentIndex
    if argumentForSegment == 0
    {
        i = 0
    }
    if argumentForSegment == 1
    {
        i += 2
    }
    else if argumentForSegment == 2   //  <==== here
    {
        i += Int(arc4random_uniform(100))
    }
    print(argumentForSegment)
    prwtoText.text = "\(i)"
}
```

Could someone explain why it used the priority of `else` although the value was zero when printing `argumentForSegment`? In other words why when I had an `else` alone for the value of `argumentForSegment == 0` it chose the `else` instead of the first statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Could someone explain why it used the priority of else although the
>   value was zero when printing argumentForSegment? In other words why
>   when I had an else alone for the value of argumentForSegment == 0 it
>   chose the else instead of the first statement?

When you have a situation where the code is not behaving as you expect, it is helpful to step through it in the debugger, or add some diagnostic `print` statements.

For example:

```
func action()
{
    let argumentForSegment = segment.selectedSegmentIndex
    if argumentForSegment == 0
    {
        print("In first block")
        i = 0
    }
    if argumentForSegment == 1
    {
        print("In second block")
        i += 2
    }
    else
    {
        print("In third block")
        i += Int(arc4random_uniform(100))
    }
    print(argumentForSegment)
    prwtoText.text = "\(i)"
}
```

If you do this, you will notice that when `argumentForSegment` is `0`, the output will be:

```
In first block
In third block
```

So, the problem is not that it is choosing the third block over the first.  The problem is that it is doing both.  You want it to stop after it has detected that `argumentForSegment` is `0`, so add an `else` to the second conditional statement so that it only does that when the first conditional statement failed:

```
func action()
{
    let argumentForSegment = segment.selectedSegmentIndex
    if argumentForSegment == 0
    {
        i = 0
    }
    else if argumentForSegment == 1  // added "else" here
    {
        i += 2
    }
    else
    {
        i += Int(arc4random_uniform(100))
    }
    print(argumentForSegment)
    prwtoText.text = "\(i)"
}
```

Comment: so if we have the same condition in if/else statements it chooses the latest one? That's ridiculous.. Is this the default behaviour? It really makes i=0 but then reassigns the value for else(i += Int(arc4random_uniform(100)))

Comment: The problem is that you have 2 separate `if` statements.  The first `if` checks if the value is `0` and does something.  The second, completely separate `if` does something if the value is `1` `else` is does something else if the value is not `1` which INCLUDES `0`.  By adding the `else` as I showed, it makes one `if-else if-else` statement that will only do one thing.

Comment: in other words if i have more than one if and an else it checks each and everyone of them. It doesn't stop at the first condition where it's true but continues until it reaches the else.it feels kinda funny to me that 
`if i == 0
{
    print("0")
}
if i == 1
{
    print("1")
}
else
{
    print("else")
}`

and `if i = 0` it prints first and else condition but `if i = 1` it only prints the second

Answer (score 1):

To improve on Vacawama's answer, you can format this much easier by using a `switch` statement:

```
func action() {

    let argumentForSegment = segment.selectedSegmentIndex

    switch argumentForSegment {
    case 0:
        i = 0
    case 1:
        i += 1
    case 2:
        i += Int(arc4random_uniform(100))
    default:
        break
    }

    print(argumentForSegment)
    prwtoText.text = "\(i)"

}
```

it's much more clean for this type of thing.

*(thanks, vacawama)*

Comment: `case 1` needs to be `i += 2` and `default` would probably be better served with a `fatalError()` message.

Comment: i didn't really want to make it using a `switch/case` but thanks for answering. Gonna give you and up vote for effort :p